# Axis 1.4 - Enable MTOM

Tags: java, xml, soap, axis

I am working on a web service project that uses Axis 1.4. The stub and classes are built from the Eclipse Generate Client tool and a provided WSDL. I am able to upload files without issue but I am unable to download files. Requested files are sent back using MTOM. My Request and Responses are formatted correctly but I am getting the following error:

```
Axis Fault string: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SimpleDeserializer encountered a child element, which is NOT expected, in something it was trying to deserialize.
```

I have set the following but it does not appear to help:

```
getStub()._setProperty(Call.ATTACHMENT_ENCAPSULATION_FORMAT,Call.ATTACHMENT_ENCAPSULATION_FORMAT_MTOM);
```

Any help would be great appreciated on how to resolve this and be able to access the attachment.

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getFile xmlns="endpoint">
            <input>
                <userName>USERNAME</userName>
                <passWord>PASSWORD</passWord>
                <fileName>FILENAME</fileName>
            </input>
        </getFile>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <getResponse xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime" xmlns="endpoint">
            <output>
                <fileData>
                    <xop:Include xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include" href="cid:FILEREFERENCENUMBER@apache.org"/>
                </fileData>
            </output>
        </getResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```